# Unable to sign archive for submission to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, testflight

I am trying to submit my app to TestFlight to test the changes.

On trying to create archive via Xcode, I am unable to create provisioning profile as my app ID cannot be registered to my development team. Xcode says hence that no dev profiles were found.

If I use an identity from the keychain for this, it says

"Code Signing Error: *** has conflicting provisioning settings. *** is automatically signed, but code signing identity iPhone Distribution: *** (JF2***M7JG) has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor."

(I am not admin user for the app on iTunesConnect but a developer. Using a particular setting for the profiles, I found what screenshot has been attached[image]).

Comment: The error states there's no Admin role setup, or you haven't signed into iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the project to resolve the conflict. If you prefer the manual signing then switch to it but if you prefer automatic signing then remove the selected signing identity "iPhone Distribution: *** (JF2***M7JG)" and then rebuild your archive.